# how to submit a form if the iphone is locked using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, html

I have a web page developed using jquery mobile and html5, which takes an answer from the user and submit the form to the server. This is working fine in the desktop but have some issues when i run this in iPhone. when the iPhone is locked the JavaScript never runs in the background as IOS stops all the JS when the page is not in focus or when phone is locked for performance boosting. So my page is not submitted until the user submits it manually.But i want to submit the form if the user is not active or if he locks the phone.

Is there a way to detect when an Iphone's lock button is pressed in jquery mobile ?

I have googled enough but could not find any answer though their exists similar kind of posts.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Hmmm... this sounds like a privacy violation to me. If I decided not to submit the form and lock my phone instead, I certainly would not want or expect the form to then submit on its own.

Comment: I totally agree with what you said. But here i want to submit the form with value as 'no answer' assuming the user is not interested. With this i feel i am not violating any privacy of the user.

Comment: consider this as an alternative: use google analytics. Set up a custom event for when the form IS voluntarily submitted. That way if you need data for 'not interested' parties you can just subtract the total form submissions from total visits. This should also be way more reliable and cross platform than hacking the lock button.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to catch blur event on `window`?

```
window.addEventListener('blur', function() {
    console.log('locked');
});
```

Also try

```
document.addEventListener('webkitvisibilitychange', function() {
    console.log('locked');
});
```

P.S. Not sure this will work

Comment: I had tried this but no joy. blur event gets triggered only when we do something on DOM. By locking the phone , window events  never gets triggered as per my experience.